Creating an EmptyPath class compatible with pathlib - Inheritance, Composition, or Metaclass?
I'm working on a Python project initially coded with path.py 16.4, where it was possible to create an empty Path object with Path(). After migrating to pathlib, this is no longer possible as Path() now returns the current directory (.).
My goal is to create a separate class that:

Allows creating an empty Path object
Returns '' (empty string)
Has a boolean evaluation of False
Allows using Path methods
Doesn't modify the behavior of other Path instances (their boolean evaluation should remain unchanged)

I'm considering three approaches and would like the community's opinion to understand and make the right choice:

Composition:
from pathlib import Path

class EmptyPath:
    def __init__(self):
        self._path = Path()


Inheritance
from pathlib import Path
class EmptyPath(Path):
    _flavour = type(Path())._flavour
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        self = super().__new__(cls, '')
        return self


Metaclass
from pathlib import Path

class EmptyPath(type(Path())):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, '')



The rest of the code being this :
def __bool__(self):
     """
     Override the boolean evaluation of the Path making the EmptyPath object
     falsy in boolean contexts.

     return: Always returns False.
     """
     return False

 def __str__(self):
     """
     Return a string representation of the path.
     For compatibility with path.py, this returns an empty string.
     """
     return ''

 def __repr__(self):
     """
     Return a string representation for debugging.
     """
     return f"EmptyPath('{self}')"

Which approach would be most appropriate to create an EmptyPath class compatible with pathlib? Are there specific advantages or disadvantages to each method in this context?
I should add that all variables instantiated with EmptyPath will be overridden by a pathlib path

StackOverflow is for specific problems; not for open discussions like this.
